# Good research topics for a university level paper

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, research

So I'm a high school student, and I am working on a paper which requires at least university level mathematics. I researched a lot online but yet still got nothing in my head.

I would like to do something about Algebra / Number Theory, and also maybe a little bit Analysis. I have a good knowledge of Galois Theory and a bit Algebraic Number Theory (i.e. Ideal, unique factorization...) but I really can't think of anything to do. I wanted to do something original (maybe a generalization) but achievable. Right now, I have brainstormed a few ideas (if you suggests new ideas that would be great, but you can also give suggestion to my ideas):

**1. Diophantine $m$-tuples and Elliptic curve**

I think I have read something about diophantine $m$-tuple (i.e. A set of numbers $(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_i)$ such that $a_ia_j+1$ is a perfect square for any $i<j$) and elliptic curve. There's a conjecture about this topic whether a diophantine quintuple exists (But I don't think I can solve it).

**2. Generalization of Hilbert Theorem 90**

I know that Hilbert Theorem 90 can be used to solve some diophantine equation, for example the Pythagorean triples and the Pell's equation. Therefore I'm thinking if any generalization can be made on it so that it could solve more diophantine equations.

That's all for my ideas right now. If you want you could leave a comment or an answer giving me suggestions on my topics above, which would be extremely helpful for me. If you have any more new ideas that would be even better. Thanks so much for helping me. :D

Comment: Diophantine quintuples may already have been done, if the work of He, Togbé and Ziegler makes it through peer-review (their papers claims that none exist).

Comment: You might find Richard Guy's "Unsolved Problems in Number Theory" a good resource for ideas for problems.  It should be available at any university math library.

Comment: Doing something original without an academic advisor is probably a bit ambitious. Solving a well known open problem would be too ambitious even for a PhD student. You'd probably be better off trying to fully understand, and then doing a survey of an exciting topic. If you're already familiar with elliptic curves, writing down a precise statement if the Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture, and stating the current state of affairs, is already pretty substantial. Even if you were to just focus on the "weak" version of the conjecture, you'd still see some exciting mathematics.